# How can I create an editor for a custom code using java code

Tags: java, reflection, editor

I'm reading methods from a text file and then execute them in my java program. For this I'm using java reflection. I want to know how can I create an editor for these text files so that I can have syntax coloring and code completion (and maybe later on compiling) because today these files are hard to read.

Do you have any idea where should I start looking?

Here is an example of a lines in the file:

```
a := 5;

b := 6;

sum := add(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better don't create your own text editor, it's not worth the effort. Just create some custom syntax highlighting, for example for IntellijIdea or any other text editor which you prefer. 
Example for IntellijIdea:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/custom-file-types-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: In that case, I should give the list of all the methods manually as an input to be auto-completed. Is it possible to give it via a file and what I wanted is when auto-complete a method for example I can see the number of argument needed for this method